# Variable contains name of another variable

Tags: php

I want to create assign different values in five variables.
So, I have created a while loop and inside I put this line of code

```
$count=0;
while( $count< $num_questions) { 
    $question_. $count= $_POST["question$count"]; 
}
```

I would like to know if this is the correct way to do this, as it seems that it doesn't work!

Answer (score 1):

You can use arrays for such task.

Simply add an element every iteration.

```
$questions = []; // define an empty array
$count=0;
while( $count< $num_questions) { 
    $questions[$count] = $_POST["question$count"]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Array is better than make variables in your case, do it with

`$question[$count] = $_POST["question$count"];`

If you persist in dynamicly define a variable, do it with

`${$question_. $count}= $_POST["question$count"];`